# Повернуть объект не по центру - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно по вернуть объект на 90 градусов так, чтобы была иллюзия, что он "упал на бок", при этом не использовать RigidBody. При использовании метода Rotate объект просто поворачивается по заданной оси.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вложи объект как потомок с нужным смещением и поворачивай родителя.

Comment: Нужная тебе точка нижний-правыйй угол в твоём случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

1. Создаем сферу
2. Делаем наш объект потомком от сферы
3. Перетаскиваем наш объект так, что бы его правый нижний угол совпадал с центром сферы
4. На сферу вешаем скрипт поворота, например:
   `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90f)`
5. Отключаем у сферы компоненты, кроме нашего скрипта и Transform
6. Профит! PS: сферу лучше переименовать, а метод поворота, вероятно, будет удобно сделать публичным (или protected) и обращаться из скрипта нашего объекта.
   (составлено на основе комментариев к вопросу)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: С включённым рисованием сферы]